# data entrance error Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm learning how to programming with fortran90 and i need receive data from a txt file **by the command prompt** (something like that:
 *program.exe"<"data.txt*).
at the Input txt file I'll always have a single line with  at least 6 numbers till infinity.

if the data was wrote line by line it runs fine but as single line I'm receiving the error: "traceback:not available,compile with - ftrace=frame or - ftrace=full fortran runtime error:end file"

*note: i'm using Force fortran 2.0

here is example of data:

```
0 1 0.001 5 3 1 0 -9 3
```

**edit:** just clarifying: the code is working fine itself except for  the read statement, which is a simple "read*,". ***I want know how To read a entire line from a txt once the entrance will be made by the promt command with stream direction***.
( you can see more about that here: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).
there is no need to read the code, i've posted it just for knowledge.

I'm sorry about the whole inconvenience.

here is the code so far:

```
program bissecao
implicit none
integer::cont,int,e,k,intc,t1,t2,t3
doubleprecision::ii,is,pre,prec,erro,somaa,somab,xn
doubleprecision,dimension(:),allocatable::co
t1=0
t2=0
t3=0


                                                                                       ! print*,"insira um limite inf da funcao"
read*,ii
                                                                                        !print*,"insira o limite superior da func"
read*,is
                                                                                       ! print*,"insira a precisÆo admissivel"
read*,pre
                                                                                      if (erro<=0) then !elimina criterio de parada negativo ou zero
                                                                                          Print*,"erro"
                                                                                          go to 100
                                                                                          end if
                                                                                        !print*,"insira a qtd  iteracoes admissiveis"
read*,int
                                                                                        !print*,"insira o grau da f(x)"
read*,e
                                                                                      if (e<=0) then  ! elimina expoente negativo
                                                                                          e=(e**2)**(0.5)
                                                                                          end if
allocate(co(e+1))
                                                                                        !print*, "insira os coeficientes na ordem:&
                                                                                               ! &c1x^n+...+(cn-1)x^1+cnx^0"
read(*,*)(co(k),k=e+1,1,-1)


somab=2*pre
intc=0


        do while (intc<int.and.(somab**2)**0.5>pre.and.((is-ii)**2)**0.5>pre)

           somab=0
           somaa=0
                 xn =(ii+is)/2

                     do k=1,e+1,1
                        if (ii /=0) then
                           somaa=ii**(k-1)*co(k)+somaa
                        else
                        somaa=co(1)
                        end if
       ! print*,"somaa",k,"=",somaa
                     end do
                     do k=1,(e+1),1
                       if (xn/=0) then
                       somab=xn**(k-1)*co(k)+somab
                       else
                       somab=co(1)
                       end if
        !print*,"somab",k,"=",somab
                     end do

                if ((somaa*somab)<0) then
                       is=xn
                else if((somaa*somab)>0)then
                       ii=xn
                else if ((somaa*somab)==0) then
                       xn=(ii+is)/2
                       go to 100
                end if
                intc =intc+1
                prec=is-ii
                if ((((is-ii)**2)**.5)< pre) then
                t3=1
                end if
                if (((somab**2)**.5)< pre) then
                t2=1.
                end if
                if (intc>=int) then
                t1=1
                end if
        end do
        somab=0
                      xn=(ii+is)/2
                    do k=1,(e+1),1
                       if (xn/=0) then
                       somab=xn**(k-1)*co(k)+somab
                       else
                       somab=co(1)
                       end if
                     end do


100 write(*,'(A,F20.15,A,F20.15,A,A,F20.15,A,F20.15,A,I2)'),"I:[",ii,",",is,"]","raiz:",xn,"Fraiz:",somab,"Iteracoes:",intc

end program   !----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have a look at your post and ask yourself *Have I made it easy for people to read my code ?*  Or, to be blunt: what you have posted is a mess and I, for one, am not even going to try to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program, you are using the "list-directed input" (i.e., `read *,` or `read(*,*)`)

```
read *, ii
read *, is
read *, pre
read *, int
read *, e
read *, ( co( k ), k = e+1, 1, -1 )
```

which means that the program goes to the next line of the data file after each `read` statement (by neglecting any remaining data in the same line). So, the program works if the data file (say "multi.dat") consists of separate lines (as suggested by OP):

```
0
1
0.001
5
3
1 0 -9 3
```

But now you are trying to read an input file containing only a single line (say "single.dat")

```
0 1 0.001 5 3 1 0 -9 3
```

In this case, we need to read all the values with a single `read` statement (if list-directed input is to be used).

A subtle point here is that the range of array `co` depends on `e`, which also needs to be read by the same `read` statement. A workaround might be to just pre-allocate `co` with a sufficiently large number of elements (say 100) and read the data in a single line, e.g.,

```
integer :: k
allocate( co( 100 ) )
read *, ii, is, pre, int, e, ( co( k ), k = e+1, 1, -1 )
```

---

For completeness, here is a test program where you can choose `method` = 1 or 2 to read "multi.dat" or "single.dat".

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: int, e, k, method
    double precision :: ii, is, pre
    double precision, allocatable :: co(:)

    allocate( co( 1000 ) )

    method = 1   !! 1:multi-line-data, 2:single-line-data

    if ( method == 1 ) then
        call system( "cat multi.dat" )
        read*, ii
        read*, is
        read*, pre
        read*, int
        read*, e
        read*, ( co( k ), k = e+1, 1, -1 )
    else
        call system( "cat single.dat" )
        read*, ii, is, pre, int, e, ( co( k ), k = e+1, 1, -1 )
    endif

    print *, "Input data obtained:"
    print *, "ii  = ", ii
    print *, "is  = ", is
    print *, "pre = ", pre
    print *, "int = ", int
    print *, "e   = ", e

    do k = 1, e+1
        print *, "co(", k, ") = ", co( k )
    enddo
end program
```

You can pass the input file from standard input as

```
./a.out < multi.dat   (for method=1)
./a.out < single.dat  (for method=2)
```

Please note that "multi.dat" can also be read directly by using "<".

Comment: I learned something new... If the data is in a file, I would open the file and read the file in a more traditional fashion as I always do it that way.

Comment: I agree (I also usually do so), but sometimes it is also convenient to take the input file from standard input (like some tiny utility tools for simulation) so that the name of the input file is more flexible. Still, I don't think the data need to be one-liner, though :)